# Why aren't Transformers usually attacked by an EMP?

Tags: robots, transformers

So if the Transformers are **giant robots with electronic bodies** as referenced in the movies, shouldn't they be easily **defeated with a large EMP** (electro-magnetic pulse)?

**Assuming their suits don't act as giant Body-Armour-like faraday cages** an EMP should theoretically kill them, permanently. So **why are EMP's never considered or even mentioned** in the movies when this (seems) like it is the obvious solution?

**Plot hole?**

Comment: What makes you think they are operated by electricity? If memory serves, in the films they were powered by a piece of the _Allspark_, which is essentially handwavium.

Comment: http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse

Comment: Is that not the answer, @Valorum? That EMPs in fact _are_ used in the movies?

Answer (score -3):

Modern military,airplane tech is designed to deal with emps, futhermore emp like effects exist in nature due to thunderbolts, solar flares. Metal armor naturally acts as a faraday cage, while they must leave holes in it for some gear.  military tech also includes tech like zener dials and other inventions, that designed to prevent too much power from going on the circuits, shut them off when a emp hits. Plus a circuit can be built to take extra power thus offering extra protection from EMP.

The point of all this is that if modern military and planes can protect themselves from emp, highly advanced alien war machines are almost protected from emp. This could be overcame with a intense enough emp exposure, but still it would limit emp usefulness. I would not be surprised if many transformers weapons includes EMP elements.

Comment: "Zener dial"???